# Delphi 10.4 error using assets\internal in the Remote Path field

Tags: delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm making a mobile application in Delphi 10.4. When adding a file (.txt) to the implementation, I use `.\assets\internal` in the Remote Path, to access it during execution, but an error occurs:

> [PAClient Warning] Warning: W0006 Invalid file mode: IOS\Teste Deployment\deployedassets.txt, ignored. Possible values are "0", "1", "2", "3", "5".

If I only use `.\` in the Remote Path, I will not be able to access the file, as this is not the correct path on the cell phone.

The `deployedassets.txt` file is created by Delphi during debug.